# Programmatically generate if elif elif elif else

Tags: python, if-statement, dry

I would like to condense some wet code that looks like this:

```
if slips[i] < 3000:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], 0, 0, 0)
    # setBackgroundOpacity deliberately omitted here
elif slips[i] < 3700:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], .2, .4, .2)
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
elif slips[i] < 4100:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], 0, 1, 0)
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
elif slips[i] < 4500:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], 0, 0, 1)
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
else:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], 1, 0, 0)
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
```

Each time this snippet of code is repeated, the only things that change are the background canvas (`wheel['slip']` in this case), and the numbers in the if elif else's.

My first thought to dry this up was to make something that could be used like this:

```
if_replacer(wheel['slip'], slips[i], 3000, 3700, 4100, 4500)

def if_replacer(canvas, value, *args):
    # idunno
```

My question is, how would I programmatically generate the if elif else's? I know I could hard-code it like so:

```
def if_replacer(canvas, value, c1, c2, c3, c4):
    if value < c1:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(canvas, 0, 0, 0)
        return
    elif value < c2:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(canvas, .2, .4, .2)
    elif value < c3:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(canvas, 0, 1, 0)
    elif value < c4:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(canvas, 0, 0, 1)
    else:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(canvas, 1, 0, 0)
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(canvas, 1)
```

But I'm interested if there is a succinct and Pythonic method to accomplish this.

edit: A lot of excellent answers, but alas I can only mark one of them as accepted (though all valid solutions were upvoted). I accepted the answer that I implemented in my code, but for anyone else who stumbles across this question, do take a look at the other solutions, they're all excellent. And, thanks to everyone who wrote an answer.

Comment: did you intentionally omit the `ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)` in the first case?

Comment: @TrevorMerrifield they appear to be special casing it in their "hard coded" example... so I'm guessing it's not just a missing line... but we never know...

Comment: @TrevorMerrifield Yes, that is deliberate

Comment: I'd use a partial function to reduce the repetition, but otherwise I think your existing structure is the clearest (i.e., most maintainable for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution.

```
def least_bound_index(value, bounds):
    """return the least index such that value < bounds[i], or else len(bounds)""" 
    for i, b in enumerate(bounds):
        if value < b:
            return i
    return i+1

bounds = [3000, 3700, 4100, 4500]
bgcolors = [(0, 0, 0), (.2, .4, .2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]

i = least_bound_index(slips[i], bounds)
ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], *bgcolors[i])
if i > 0:
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
```

Note that `least_bound_index` could also be called `index_between` because you could imagine [a, b, c, d] on a number line, and it would tell you where the value lands out of these choices:

```
  a   b   c   d
^   ^   ^   ^   ^
0   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: It took me quite a while to follow this, I wanted to ask what `return i+1` does but I finally figured it out to save myself the embarrassment: if `value` is not within any of the bounds, then it must be the last color, so this line adds one to select it. This avoids the "infinity hack" that asks if `value` is between the last bound and infinity. Quite a clever solution in my opinion. This is the one I finally ended up using, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I also just added another way to think about it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case 'setBackgroundOpacity' was omitted by mistake or it doesn't matter if it is included in the first case as well, this is a solution you might be looking for:

```
color_map = [ (3000, 0, 0, 0), 
              (3700, .2, .4, .2), 
              (4100, 0, 1, 0), 
              (4500, 0, 0, 1), 
              (10**10, 1, 0, 0) ]

for i, (c, r, g, b) in enumerate(color_map):
    if value < c:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], r, g, b)
        if i > 0:
            ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
        break
```

Edit: saw the comment about the setBackgroundOpacity function

Edit2: Fixed the typo and added an alternative solution to 10**10

```
color_map = [ (3000, 0, 0, 0), 
              (3700, .2, .4, .2), 
              (4100, 0, 1, 0), 
              (4500, 0, 0, 1), 
              (float("inf"), 1, 0, 0) ]

for i, (c, r, g, b) in enumerate(color_map):
    if value < c:
        ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'], r, g, b)
        if i > 0:
            ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
        break
```

Comment: This may have unintended side-effects. Once you find a match, you should break out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, noticed this as soon as I posted. Fixed now, thank you

Comment: One minor typo: `setBackgroundCOlor` should be `setBackgroundColor`. This solution is intuitive and easy to follow, I'd say very pythonic in terms of control flow, but the `10**10` makes me a little uncomfortable.

Comment: Indeed, it wasn't the optimal choice for the max number. Fixed, along with the typo.

Answer (score 2):

My take on it (untested as to the actual `ac...` calls):

```
from functools import partial

mapping = [
    (3000, (0, 0, 0), None),
    (3700, (.2, .4, .2), 1),
    (4100, (0, 1, 0), 1),
    (4500, (0, 0, 1), 1),
    (float('inf'), (1, 0, 0), 1)
]

def if_replacer(canvas, value, mapping):
    set_color = partial(ac.setBackgroundColor, canvas)
    set_opacity = partial(ac.setBackgroundOpacity, canvas)
    for limit, vals, opacity in lookup:
        if value < limit:
            set_color(*vals)
            if opacity is not None:
                set_opacity(opacity)
            break
```

Then if for some reason you do have to pick up new ranges, then you can do something like:

```
from bisect import insort_left
insort_left(mapping, (4300, (1, 1, 1), 0))
```

Which'll update `mapping` to be:

```
[(3000, (0, 0, 0), None),
 (3700, (0.2, 0.4, 0.2), 1),
 (4100, (0, 1, 0), 1),
 (4300, (1, 1, 1), 0),
 (4500, (0, 0, 1), 1),
 (inf, (1, 0, 0), 1)]
```

Comment: This is a neat and professional-looking solution, but unfortunately I can't use `functools` since this is being run in a stripped-down version of Python - specifically, it's run as an app within Assetto Corsa. I can't even use `dict.items()` here.

Comment: @DavidTan yowsers - I certainly don't envy you there :)

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [[0,0,0],[.2,.4,.2],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
threshold = [3000,3700,4100,4500]
if slips[i] >= 4500:
    ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'],1,0,0)
else:
    for x in range(4):
        if slips[i] < threshold[x]:
            ac.setBackgroundColor(wheel['slip'],c[x][0],c[x][1],c[x][2])
            break
if slips[i] >= 3000:
    ac.setBackgroundOpacity(wheel['slip'], 1)
```

This is one alternative, but I do personally prefer @mpurg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def problem1_5(age):
    """Prints according to ages"""
    if age(1<7):
        print("Have a glass of milk")
    elif age(7<21):
        print("Have a cake")
    elif age>21:
        print("Have a martini")
    else:
        print(end='')
```